# Flutter: Get ListView size to create dynamic item sizes

Tags: listview, flutter, dart

I'm trying to create a ListView in Flutter where the total sum of its items' width is the width of the ListView itself.

In other words: I have 24 items, and I want each one to have an extent of [ListView.width]/24. However, I cannot seem to get the width of the list view inside of its builder.

I tried using context.size.width:

```
 itemBuilder: (context, i) {
 return Container(
            width: context.size.width,
 //And so on....
```

but I get the following error:

> Cannot get size during build.

I also tried using Extended at each of the item's root, but it predictably didn't work.

Is there any way to obtain the width of the item's parent (the list view) and use it to calculate its extent dynamically?

Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure i fully understand your question, you know the size of each listview item and you're trying to figure out the total width of your listview, correct? If not, it's going to be a **chicken or egg** situation based on my understanding.

Comment: No, I want to know the width of the list view in order to calculate each item's width. I know the content it potentially infinite, but in this case, I mean the bounds of the listview on the screen regardless of the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to get the `ListView` to display some items horizontally across the widget, put the children inside a `Row` and wrap each with an `Expanded`:

```dart
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: 1,
  itemBuilder: (_, i) => Row(
    children: [
      Expanded(child: Container(height: 50, color: Colors.red)),
      Expanded(child: Container(height: 50, color: Colors.blue)),
      Expanded(child: Container(height: 50, color: Colors.red)),
      Expanded(child: Container(height: 50, color: Colors.blue)),
      Expanded(child: Container(height: 50, color: Colors.red)),
      Expanded(child: Container(height: 50, color: Colors.blue)),
      Expanded(child: Container(height: 50, color: Colors.red)),
      Expanded(child: Container(height: 50, color: Colors.blue)),
      Expanded(child: Container(height: 50, color: Colors.red)),
      Expanded(child: Container(height: 50, color: Colors.blue)),
      Expanded(child: Container(height: 50, color: Colors.red)),
      Expanded(child: Container(height: 50, color: Colors.blue)),
      Expanded(child: Container(height: 50, color: Colors.red)),
      Expanded(child: Container(height: 50, color: Colors.blue)),
      Expanded(child: Container(height: 50, color: Colors.red)),
      Expanded(child: Container(height: 50, color: Colors.blue)),
      Expanded(child: Container(height: 50, color: Colors.red)),
      Expanded(child: Container(height: 50, color: Colors.blue)),
      Expanded(child: Container(height: 50, color: Colors.red)),
      Expanded(child: Container(height: 50, color: Colors.blue)),
    ],
  ),
),
```

[image]

If you're trying to do this with a `ListView` in a horizontal orientation, then I would recommend to not use a `ListView` at all. Just use the `Row` in the first place.

---

**EDIT:** Since this answer was made, Dart has released a version that allows loops in list definitions. As such, a more proper way to do the above would be this:

```dart
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: 1,
  itemBuilder: (_, i) => Row(
    children: [
      for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            height: 50, 
            color: j.isEven ? Colors.blue : Colors.red,
          ),
        ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Comment: I was so invested in the ListView Approach I didn't really think of doing that.. Unless there is a more elegant way to do this using ListView in order not to repeat my item widgets 24 times, this is a valid answer. Thanks

Comment: @JacoboKoenig This is an example of achieving the effect. The "more elegant" way would be to generate the child widgets (e.g. with a `buildChild` method) that returns each child wrapped in an `Expanded`, store each of those children in a list, and pass that list to the `children` property of the row.

Answer (score 0):

```
ScheduleBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((duration) {
    RenderBox box = _keyOfTheWidget.currentContext.getRenderObject();
    
    // For size of wiget
    Size size = box.size;

    // For position
    Offset offset = box.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);    

    setState(() => newSize = size);
});
```

Use this method... its postFrameCallback that happens once the widget is rendered.. you can get the size of the widget and then repaint the widget to be in your desired size.

[Like here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14488#issuecomment-410259648)